# How to have conditional project reference in a vcxproj file

Tags: msbuild, vcxproj

I have a VisualC++ project as a vcxproj and I need to have one of the ProjectDependency elements conditionally included.

I've tried a few different ways and nothing seems to be working.

In my fubar.vcxproj I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(BuildRaster)'=='True'">
    <ProjectReference Include="Raster.vcxproj" Condition="'$(BuildRaster)'=='True'">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <Private>false</Private>
      <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>false</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
      <LinkLibraryDependencies>true</LinkLibraryDependencies>
      <UseLibraryDependencyInputs>false</UseLibraryDependencyInputs>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

In the collector .proj file that I use I have this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FUBARProject Include="$(Proj_Root)\fubar.vcxproj"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BuildWithRaster">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(FUBARProject)" Properties="ExportIncludes=true;Constants=IncludeRaster;BuildRaster=True"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="BuildWithoutRaster">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(FUBARProject)" Properties="ExportIncludes=true;Constants=ExcludeRaster;BuildRaster=False"/>
</Target>
```

There's actually over a hundred dependent projects so this is only a snippet of the stubbed out version. A conditional ProjectReference seems to work for a csproj but not for a vcxproj. I've tried putting the conditional on the ProjectReference and also on the ItemGroup element; neither made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, the condition clause does work in a vcxproj file. I actually had a different dependency that brought in the same project that I wasn't aware of until I turned on verbosity in the build.